# Showing http server response in html

Tags: http, request, httpresponse

> I'm trying to create a page that will check websites for server
>   status.
>
> So on the page I need to obtain a response code of 200 from the
>   server, and place an icon on the page to declare status. I now that
>   there are examples out there, but they are only for individual sites.
>   This project is to either host locally or my server, so that I have a
>   list is customer site, and the status of there websites.
>
> Is this possible?

**EDIT :** I have found a way to do this now, but cannot point the Java to the correct site. What I have done is shorten the **www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/echelonservices.co.uk** site to **isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk**. However, I am having problems doing this. All I

Ultimatly what I want to do is look for ***It's just you!*** or ***It's not just you!*** within the container ID of: "**< div id="container">**" within the source of the resulting page of **isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk**

Here is what I have come up with and failed misserably so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Specify where the sctipt should be running the code against.
window.location.protocol = "http"
window.location.host = "isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk"

//Look for the Class ID and output to a variable.
element = document.getElementById('container');
var Status = element.textContent || element.innerText;

//If the "Status" says: UP write UP, DOWN write DOWN and anything else write Status could not be determined!
if (Status=="UP") {document.write('<div style="color:#00BB00;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">UP</div>')}
else {if (Status=="DOWN") {document.write('<div style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">DOWN</div>')}
else {document.write('<div style="color:#EDA200;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">WARNING:<br>Status could not be determined!</div>')};};
</script>
```

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: You need to do the checks from your server, because the AJAX same-origin policy prevents doing this from Javascript in the browser.

Comment: I think www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com may have an API, since there's a Chrome extension that uses it.

Comment: Thanks Blender - When you say platform, what do you refer to? If OS Its Win7, if the way I do it, I guess I'm happy with Ajax/Javascript. Preferably without the PHP element, as thinking about it now, I want to run it locally opposed to publishing it on a webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up though Barmar. I have looked @ "downforeveryoneorjustme.com" but cannot get my head around the API that they are using. Have attempted to rip the API JScipt it was using, but still unsure. Any Ideas?

Comment: Just added an edit to the original description. ;)